# How can I get PixlUI for Android custom fonts working?

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am trying to use [PixlUI](https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI/blob/master/README.md) to implement custom fonts into my Android app using Xamarin. I've followed these steps:

1. Added a new Android Java Bindings Library to my main solution
2. Added [pixlui-1-0-5.jar](https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI/releases/download/v1.0.5/pixlui-1-0-5.jar) to the jars folder
3. Under properties for pixlui-1-0-5.jar i've set the "include in deploy" to true
4. Tested my new Android Java Bindings Library and it builds fine without errors
5. Under the main project i've added my font to the assets/fonts folder
6. Under references i've added the pixlUI binding library
7. In my main.axml i've placed this code:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">

   <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewpixl"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello_world"
   pixlui:copyandpaste="false"
   pixlui:clearclipboardcontent="true"
   pixlui:typeface="Lato-Light.ttf" 
   android:layout_below="@id/btnRebate"
    />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

When I build my project it fails with 10 errors all referencing "already contains a definition for..." with error cs0102 inside the pixlUI files.

Ex: .../pixlUI/obj/Debug/generated/src/Com.Neopixl.Pixlui.Components.Edittext.IEditTextBatchListener.cs(59,59): Error CS0102: The type `Com.Neopixl.Pixlui.Components.Edittext.AddNewCharEventArgs' already contains a definition for`p0' (CS0102) (pixlUI)

I've tried troubleshooting this but it appears to be either an issue with pixlUI or conflict with something already in my solution. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should change the Build Action for the pixelui.jar to *EmbeddedJar*.

Then you need to add the following to your binding's *Metadata.xml* file:

```xml
<!-- Bindings added to rename event parameters  -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext']/interface[@name='EditTextBatchListener']/method[@name='addNewChar']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="name">editText</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext']/interface[@name='EditTextBatchListener']/method[@name='deleteKeyboardButton']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="name">editText</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext']/interface[@name='EditTextBatchListener']/method[@name='deleteKeyboardButton']/parameter[@name='p1']" name="name">emptyText</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext']/interface[@name='EditTextFocusListener']/method[@name='loseFocus']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="name">editText</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext']/interface[@name='EditTextFocusListener']/method[@name='requestFocus']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="name">editText</attr>
```

Rebuild your bindings then you should be able to use it in your Android app.

Here's a screenshot from the sample project:

[image: Screenshot of PixlUI on Xamarin]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! There wasn't a mention of adding anything to the metadaa.xml file on the PixlUI github so I missed that part.

Comment: That's actually specific to Xamarin. The binding process pretty much takes the Java types and creates the appropriate C# types. The problem is that sometimes the automated process doesn't handle everything correctly. The Metadata.xml file gives you more control over how the C# types are generated.